# OneSignal-Cordova-SDK fails when added on ionic 2 project

Tags: angular, ionic2, cordova-plugins, ionic3, onesignal

OneSignal-Cordova-SDK fails when added on ionic 2 project
Latest version is 2.2.2

> Failed to install 'onesignal-cordova-plugin': Error: pod: Command
>   failed with exit code 31
>       at ChildProcess.whenDone (APP_LOCATION/platforms/ios/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:169:23)
>       at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
>       at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
>       at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:927:16)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
>
> Failed to restore plugin "onesignal-cordova-plugin" from config.xml.
>   You might need to try adding it again. Error: Error: pod: Command
>   faile`enter code here`d with exit code 31

Answer (score 2):

I actually figured out the problem.

if you add(or upgrade) one signal, it uses the latest dependencies that have to be downloaded using cocoapods.

running "pod repo update"

should fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just follow these steps.

1. Remove `node_modules` folder
2. `npm i`

If it won't work after that too:

Then uninstall `onesignal plugin` and reinstall it again.